# React / Nextjs SSR & API - Preference of Cloud Architecture

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, devops, next.js

If you have an SSR web-server in Node.js and an API (also in Node.js) to host, is it 'generally' a better design to host and scale these grouped together, or to use each node in the cluster for both? I've attached a diagram to better explain what I mean.

The reason I'm asking this as a lot of projects on the internet show Express API's & React SSR's being built within the same repository and deployed together. This generally goes against what I thought was standard procedure but I'm beginning to doubt myself and wanted some input from the community.

[image: Two cloud architectures diagrammed next to each other for comparrison]

Within configuration A, every cloud server has two processes, a next.js web server and a node.js express API. Configuration B has these two split out.

Here are a few of the obvious pro's - cons I can see of both but I was wondering if I'm overlooking something obvious or if there is a reason why most developers go with one path over the other.

**Configuration A**

*Pros*

- Lower costs (network traffic between SSR and API can be done locally)
- Easier to setup & maintain the cloud infrastructure
- Share code (all in JS - by including local modules of code)

*Cons*

- Might not scale well (if each server the API uses 80% of the CPU, then you're forced to scale both even though you don't need the extra SSR capacity)
- Security risk (if someone breaks into your web-server, then they have direct access to the server that connects to the DB)
- Single point of failure (even if only web-server is DDOS'd, the API gets affected too)

**Configuration B**

*Pros*

- Better scalability
- Better Security (if implemented correctly)
- Easier deployments (rebooting servers only affects targeted instance)

*Cons*

- Likely higher pricing
- Slower API calls from the SSR (pre-render)
- Duplicate code (like React JWT decoding etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, solution B would be the preferred approach in a production environment. As you mentioned, scalability would be much better and you have the ability to change the API nodes without affecting the SSR nodes, also traffic would be split between these two deployment groups. If you're API is getting bogged down your webpage would still be responsive to load (presuming that initial render isn't dependant on API calls). Another benefit of the second approach would be the ability to cache API calls using something like Redis or Memcache.

If you're just deploying a small project or not expecting much traffic, you probably don't need the complexity of approach B, which is why a lot of people choose to go down route A, because you simply don't need the extra complications.

Comment: Thanks, I had a gut feeling that would be the case but wanted to reach out to some other developers and see how others felt. Cheers for your input!